# The angular way of a menu

Tags: angularjs

I'm quite new to angular and am curious about how to properly "navigate" between a child object and its parent.

Let's say I've got an object like this:

```
$scope.nodes = {
                 name: "MyNodes",
                 subnodes: [
                   {
                     name: "ObjectA"
                     subnodes: [
                       name: "ObjectA_1"
                     ]
                   }, {
                     name: "ObjectB"
                   }
                 ]
               };
```

How would you go on to display "MyNodes" as default and if a user clicks on it then display "ObjectA" and "ObjectB" while also having some sort of way to go back to show "MyNodes"?

Something like this:

```
| < Go back   |
| Object A  > |
| Object B    |
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

I'm using this repeater:

```
    <div data-ng-repeat="node in myNodes.subnodes">
        <div data-ng-click="">
           BACK
        </div>
        <div class="item">
           <div>
              {{ node.name }}
           </div>
           <div data-ng-if="node.subnodes.length > 0" 
                data-ng-click="setCurrentNode(node)">
              NEXT
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

By `setCurrentNode(node)` I change the object myNodes. I do not have any idea however how I could proceed this way and also be able to get the "BACK"-button to work.

I'm guessing I have to rethink the architecture?

Comment: Nodes, subnodes, sounds like a tree to me.

Comment: I don't think this is an angular question really - more of a javascript one. When you say navigate are we talking about states?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point @Christophe Roussy

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular in particular. you implement it in angular as you would implement it in any other language/framework. by constructing it somehow... you will have to be more precise if you want some help on that

Comment: @PatrickKelleter I've gotten as far as to use an ng-repeater allowing me to print out the name and get "deeper" and show its subnodes respective names etc, but I can't figure out how to "get back" to the parent again. Not sure I'm explaining very well, not very familiar with angular. I'll add an example.

Comment: Normally would use an href and url . How you shape those depends on your router configuration. It really sounds like you should study some routing tutorials

Comment: @guitarzero a tree data structure is made up of nodes within nodes (related to recursion), example: https://www.grobmeier.de/recursive-menus-angularjs-templates-01082013.html